# bash script error using {} for multiple commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm writing a bash script (below) and executing it using

```
sudo bash ./script.bash
```

result error:

```
line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
```

the script:

```
getent passwd myuser > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "info: user myuser already exists"
else
    sudo useradd -M myuser > /dev/null || { echo "ERROR: could not create user myuser."; exit 1 }
    echo "info: user myuser created successfully"
fi
```

if I remove the line:

```
|| { echo "ERROR: could not create user fiminion"; exit 1 }
```

everything seems to work.. I don't understand what am I missing.. :/

Comment: Please ensure that error-messages are from the same code that you post.

Comment: Is it satisfactory to just remove `{` and `}`? I would also replace all occurrences of `myuser` with `$1`, so the program is run as `./program.sh myuser`

Comment: You should add a `;` between `exit 1` and `}`.

Comment: @mosvy Seems like you are  right! =) all additional commands should end with ";" thanks man!